# Python For Grammar

Tags: python

I'm newbie to programming python. I built Beremiz program on Linux, I got this error.

```
File "Beremiz.py", line 164, in <module>
    from ProjectController import ProjectController, MATIEC_ERROR_MODEL, ITEM_CONFNODE
  File "/DATA1/UTILITY/Beremiz/beremiz/ProjectController.py", line 16, in <module>
    import connectors
  File "/DATA1/UTILITY/Beremiz/beremiz/connectors/__init__.py", line 34
    for name in listdir(_base_path) 
      ^


connectors = {name:_GetLocalConnectorClassFactory(name)
                  for name in listdir(_base_path)
                      if path.isdir(path.join(_base_path, name))
                          and not name.startswith("__")}
```

This syntax is not build of python. What is problem?
Thanks for all.

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? Your code may be using some newer syntax that isn't supported in older versions of Python.

Comment: This runs fine on Python 3.x, make sure you're using the version for which your software is designed.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure that your version of Python supports the dictionary comprehension syntax. This requires Python >= 2.7 or Python >= 3.

Otherwise you can modify the code like this:

```
connectors = dict((name, _GetLocalConnectorClassFactory(name))
                  for name in listdir(_base_path)
                      if path.isdir(path.join(_base_path, name))
                          and not name.startswith("__"))
```